# Limit amount of workflow executions in specific state (semaphore?)

Tags: netflix-conductor, workflow-engine

I am using Netflix Conductor (which meanwhile became Orkes Conductor) to model a workflow.
There are five steps in a sequence. The first four perform checks that are used to 'limit some risk' before the fifth really takes action.

Now I'd like to define a maximum number of workflow executions where the risk is being checked. Or in other words: I want to limit the number of workflow executions in one of the four states.

The need to limit parallel executions has emerged elsewhere as well:

- https://github.com/Netflix/conductor/pull/1893
- https://github.com/Netflix/conductor/issues/2066
- https://github.com/Netflix/conductor/discussions/2430

How to model the workflow in Conductor?